# How to prove $x^nx^m = x ^{n + m}$ where $n$ or $m$ are negative.

Tags: analysis

In my text book I am given some properties of exponentiation, one of them being

$$x^nx^m = x ^{n + m} \text{ where } x,y \text{ are rational and } n,m \text{ are natural.} $$

which I have completed the proof via induction. Now I am asked to prove

$$x^nx^m = x ^{n + m} \text{ where } x,y \text{ are rational and } n,m \text{ are integers.} $$

I am also given

$$\text{Let } x \text{ be a non-zero rational number. Then for any negative integer} -n \text{, we define } x^{-n}:= \frac{1}{x^n} $$

I can split the proof into cases. If $n,m$ are both positive we are done.

Now the case $n>0$ and $m < 0$.

Let $k>0$ and $-m = k$

then $x^nx^m = x^nx^{-k} = x^n\frac{1}{x^k} $

I am stumped.

Comment: If you multiply $x^{n - k}$ and your $x^n x^{-k}$ by $x^k$ you get the same result, so they are the same.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks :)